# C# implement two different generic interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm not sure what I'm wanting to do is even a good idea, but here's the problem anyway:  I have `MyClass` which I want to implement two different types of the generic `IEnumerable` class, e.g.

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>,
                       IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>>
```

Now, the problem with doing this is when I try to define necessary methods from the interfaces, the compiler complains "Type 'MyClass' already defines a member called 'GetEnumerator' with the same parameter types".  This is because I have these two methods:

```
public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>> GetEnumerator() { ... }
public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator() { ... }
```

I have to have `GetEnumerator()` with no parameters because of the interface, and the only thing that differs is the return type, which is not allowed.

Here are what I see as my options:

1. I was considering having a "main" `IEnumerable` generic type which `MyClass` would implement, and then just adding extra methods that differ by parameters and not just return type (e.g. `Add`), without implementing the extra generic interfaces.
2. I could create a generic base class for `MyClass`, call it `MyBaseClass<T>`, and it would implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, string>>`.  Then, I would have different versions of `MyClass`, e.g. `MyClass<string>` and `MyClass<MyEnum>`.

Which seems preferable here, or am I missing something that would be an even better solution?

Comment: You can't inherit interface (or more of them).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973861.aspx

Comment: In short - interfaces gets implemented and not inherited.

Comment: Thanks--I fixed my terminology.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use explicit interface declarations in order to get different implementations for each of the two interfaces that you are implement.  For example:

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>,
                   IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>>
{
    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // return your enumerator here
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // return your enumerator here
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        var me = this as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>;
        return me.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

However, because IEnumerable<> derives from IEnumerable, you'll have to pick which one you want to return from the IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() call.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicity implement each interface like this:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.GetEnumerator() { ... }
IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>> IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>>.GetEnumerator() { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461.aspx) to implement interfaces with conflicting methods. However, if you implement two `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces, it will cause some rather annoying issues for things like `foreach` loops. I once tried this for something and promptly went back to implementing 1 `IEnumerable` interface, and offering the other as a property of the object.

Comment: 5 answers about explicit interfaces in 2 minutes. :D

Comment: Yes, but only mine offers an improved solution :deal: :)

Comment: I won't participate in "who will improve his answer better" race. :)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to implement [interfaces explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(VS.71).aspx).

Downside - you would always need to cast MyClass.